# Terminating With Uncaught Exception of Type NSException - TableView

Tags: swift, swift3, appdelegate, nsexception

I'm trying to create an app where the user clicks a button on the first page and it goes to another page with a table on it. But when I click that button, all that comes up is an error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

and a Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT on this line in AppDelegate.swift:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

Help?

First view controller - the one with the button (ViewController):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


@IBOutlet weak var textGifteeName: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var pickerAge: UIPickerView!
var age = String()
let itemsAge: [String] = ["1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", "1965", "1966", "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", "1973", "1974", "1975", "1976", "1977", "1978", "1979", "1980", "1981", "1982", "1983", "1984", "1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsAge.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return itemsAge[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView , didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    age = itemsAge[row]
}


@IBOutlet weak var labelGifteeLocationsPreview: UILabel!

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

That's all other information the user puts in, which all act fine. 
I have the button on the storyboard, I did not put it in the code of ViewController.

Here's the view controller with the table (LocationsTableController):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


@IBOutlet weak var tableLocations: UITableView!
let itemsLocations: [String] = ["Pacific Northwest", "West Coast", "The West", "Midwest", "Great Lakes", "The South", "New England"]
var locationsPreviewtext = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsLocations.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellLocations: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()
    cellLocations.textLabel?.text = itemsLocations[indexPath.row]
    return cellLocations
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    locationsPreviewtext.append(itemsLocations[indexPath.row])
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if locationsPreviewtext.isEmpty {
        return
    } else {
        let ind = index(ofAccessibilityElement: locationsPreviewtext[indexPath.row])
        print(ind)
        if ind == NSNotFound {
            print(locationsPreviewtext[indexPath.row])
            print(ind)
            locationsPreviewtext.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you have an outlet that was created in storyboard and linked to the your view controller. You then deleted the outlet but not the link. You can "show the Connection inspector" to see if any unused link exists.

Comment: I redid all my connections and deleted unnecessary stuff. It works now, thank you!